# Kestrel server issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, kestrel-http-server, kestrel

I am new to Asp .Net Core. I need to know the maximum number of parallel requests kestrel web server can handle and how to monitor them. I tried to use Prometheus to monitor but it didn't helped.

Answer (score 1):

About 7 million rqts / sec: https://www.ageofascent.com/2019/02/04/asp-net-core-saturating-10gbe-at-7-million-requests-per-second/

Any monitoring system is working fine, you can use AppInsights, any advanced logging lib like Serilog ...

Comment: **Daboul** thank you for your answer. But i also want to know that how to monitor each request. I am sending around 10000 request from 2 devices(PC's) parallely, I need to check which request is executing and which request is waiting for execution.

Comment: I'm not sure I see what is the issue. If you use any logging mechanism, including the one shipped with Asp.Net Core (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1) you can activate the logging for Microsoft.AspNetCore layer you will see everything: when the request reach the server, and when the answer is sent back to client,  including the execution time. Each Request comes with a RequestId that you can use to correlate your request. So adding some logging, even basic ones, should give you visibility.